# Getting a variable from a Multidimensional Json decode array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find what card type the customers has used. I am testing with this:

```
$request_body = '{"id":8799347,"order_id":"1854059","accepted":true,"type":"Payment","text_on_statement":null,"branding_id":null,"variables":{},"currency":"USD","state":"new","operations":[{"id":1,"type":"authorize","amount":8996,"pending":false,"qp_status_code":"20000","qp_status_msg":"Approved","aq_status_code":"000","aq_status_msg":"Approved","data":{},"callback_url":"http://www.mywebsite.com/callback.php","callback_success":null,"callback_response_code":null,"created_at":"2015-11-11T11:08:40+00:00"}],"metadata":{"type":"card","brand":"visa","last4":"0008","exp_month":1,"exp_year":2019,"country":"US","is_3d_secure":false,"hash":"454545454878","number":null,"customer_ip":"1.1.2.23","customer_country":"US","fraud_suspected":false,"fraud_remarks":[]},"link":null,"shipping_address":null,"invoice_address":null,"test_mode":true,"acquirer":"via","facilitator":null,"created_at":"2015-11-11T11:08:34Z","balance":0}';

$request_array = json_decode($request_body, TRUE);

echo $request_array['brand']."<br />";
```

But I think it appears within a Multidimensional array as mentioned here (http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php) and I have tried variations of this:

```
echo $request_array[1]['brand']."<br />"
```

and

```
echo $request_array[1]->brand."<br />"
```

but I can not get the variable for brand.

Comment: use `print_r` on the array to see it's structure, it's really useful

Answer (score 0):

Oh.

```
echo $request_array['metadata']['brand']."<br />";
```

Comment: Could you explain why this fixed your problem?